# How to access a file with only part of the file name?

Tags: java, file

I'm trying to instantiate a File variable, but only know part of the file name. I.e. I know that the file name starts with "pass_231_" but don't know the rest. Is this even possible?

Comment: use file.listfiles on the directory and compare all the file names whether they start with `pass_231_` and identify the file you want to use.

Comment: Worst case scenario you scan the whole directory structure looking for a file with a matching name. So yes, it's possible, although it would help to know at least the directory it's in.

Answer (score 3):

If you know what directory it's in, yes. You can use a [`FileFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileFilter.html):

```
final String prefix = "pass_231_"
File dir = ... ;
File[] candidates = dir.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File pathname) {
        return pathname.getName().startsWith(prefix);
    }
});
// candidates will contain all files starting with "pass_231_"
```

If you need to search recursively (including subfolders), you can do this:

```
String prefix = "pass_231_";
File dir = ... ;
List<File> candidates = new ArrayList<File>();
searchRecursively(dir, prefix, candidates);
// candidates will contain all files starting with "pass_231_"
```

Then `searchRecursively` looks like this:

```
public static void searchRecursively(File dir, final String prefix, List<File> candidates) {
    File[] matches = dir.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File pathname) {
            return pathname.getName().startsWith(prefix);
        }
    });
    candidates.addAll(Arrays.asList(matches));
    File[] subdirs = dir.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File pathname) {
            return pathname.isDirectory();
        }
    });
    for (File subdir : subdirs) {
        searchRecursively(subdir, prefix, candidates);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `File.listFiles(filter)` method on the directory that contains the file. More info [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28java.io.FileFilter%29).

Answer (score 1):

In case someone try to find "How to open file by part of his name", just like me a few moments ago.

```
    List<String> list = Files.walk(path)
            .map((q) -> q.getFileName().toString())
            .filter((s) -> s.contains("2019-05-25"))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    if(list.size() == 1){
        System.out.println("your file is" + list.get(0));
    } else {
        System.out.println("there are more than one file");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can list all the files in a folder, and then, once you know the full name, open the file.

See the [File.list()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#list%28%29) method.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a filter on the folder, but if the filter returns more than one file, you must decide which one to open.